# Qt - The mousePressEvent problem is not working

Tags: c++, qt

I created a polygon through the constructor and added it to the scene where I call the constructor and do all that, but now I have to make a signal by pressing the mouse on the arrow, I added mousePressEvent, but when I click I don't get the message I put into qDebug or any functionality, which might be a problem, if someone can offer a solution, thank you.

```
tranzicija.h

   class tranzicija:public QObject,public QGraphicsPolygonItem
    {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    tranzicija();
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget = 0);
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    private:
    QPolygonF pol1;
    void pomjeriproces();
    };
    
    tranzicija.cpp
    
        tranzicija::tranzicija()
    {
        pol1 << QPoint(0,45)  << QPoint(60,45) << QPoint(60,35) << QPoint(100, 50)
             << QPoint(60,65) << QPoint(60,55) << QPoint(0,55)  << QPoint(0,45);
    }
    
    void tranzicija::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
    {
            qDebug() << "The button was pressed!";
    }
    void tranzicija::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
    {
    
     QBrush pen(Qt::green);
            painter->setBrush(pen);
            painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
            painter->drawPolygon(pol1);
    
    }

dialog.cpp

    //Poligon start => ready
    tranzicija *tr = new tranzicija();
    tr->setRotation(45);
    tr->setPos(170,125);
    tr->setScale(0.8);
    scene->addItem(tr);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be really hard to help you if we don't see the relevant parts of the header and source files of your `tranzicija` class. For example it would be great to know whether the `mousePressEvent` was declared as public, protected, signal etc.

Comment: You should add this rather as a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: You are right, but unfortunately I cannot make any comments, because it requires a reputation of 50, which is just absurd.

Comment: @Adrian I set up the code so look, thank you.

Comment: @Adrian yeah, you are right, that is absurd.

Comment: @DonMarquez I have checked your code and you don't need a signal for the mouse event to work. Could you try typing just below your mousePressEvent method in Qt 'void mouseReleaseEvent'? Does the auto complete context menu come up when you are typing? If not, then probably it is because public QGraphicsItem is missing from this line: class tranzicija:public QObject,public QGraphicsPolygonItem.

According to the documentation you also must implement QRectF boundingRect() const; in your tranzicija class if you inherit from QGraphicsItem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72602746/6371123), the problem is that you never call [`QGraphicsPolygonItem::setPolygon`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicspolygonitem.html#setPolygon).  Hence the `Qt` graphics framework knows nothing about the shape/size of your graphics item and can't know when mouse actions take place on it.

Try changing your constructor to...

```
tranzicija::tranzicija ()
{
    pol1 << QPoint(0,45)  << QPoint(60,45) << QPoint(60,35) << QPoint(100, 50)
         << QPoint(60,65) << QPoint(60,55) << QPoint(0,55)  << QPoint(0,45);
    setPolygon(pol1);
}
```

You can probably also make `pol1` local to the constructor and remove it as a class member.  Also no need for the `paint` override -- the `QGraphicsPolygonItem::paint` implementation does that for you.